# Flutter: google_mobile_ads is not displayed

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

When I try to use [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads), I get the following text, and it does not work.
I also tried using [admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) and that one worked fine.

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method MobileAds#initialize on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
```

This is the `main.dart` file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp((myApp()));
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.  What I did is wrap everything in MaterialApp and put routes on my main Widget.

```
runApp( 
MaterialApp( 
routes: 
<String, WidgetBuilder>
{ '/': (BuildContext context) => 
MyApp()}
,)
,);
```

As for how this works, I don't know how it fix everything but it might help you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem to delite admob_flutter pub and reinstall pod.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).